# How to subtract datetimes / timestamps in python

Tags: python, datetime

Seems like this should be so simple but for the life of me, I can't find the answer.  I pull two datetimes/timestamps from the database:

```
2015-08-10 19:33:27.653
2015-08-10 19:31:28.209
```

How do I subtract the first from the second, preferably the result being in milliseconds? And yes, I have the date in there, too, because I need it to work at around midnight, as well.

Comment: Those are neither `datetime` objects nor timestamps. If you want them to behave as such, you'll have to convert them.

Comment: Downvoting for no research effort because a cursory glance at the documentation for Python date handling would tell you exactly how to do this.

Comment: Upvoting because this saved me time

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Parse your strings as `datetime.datetime` objects and subtract them:

```
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime("2015-08-10 19:33:27.653", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
d2 = datetime.strptime("2015-08-10 19:31:28.209", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")

print(d1 - d2)
```

Gives me:

```
0:01:59.444000
```

Also check out [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) documentation for all possible operations.

Comment: Great. This works for me. Didn't know I had to convert the string to a datetime object first.

Comment: @JeffF - You would have found that out if you had Googled "python datetime" - I highly recommend doing some searches before asking a question so you can get an idea of where to go.

Comment: `timedelta.total_seconds(d2-d1)` to get (`float`) seconds gap

Comment: this is not always giving the right answer, since you are assuming both times are in same timezone, which is not always correct

Answer (score 5):

you can do subtraction on 2 datetime objects to get the difference

```
>>> import time
>>> import datetime
>>>
>>> earlier = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> time.sleep(10)
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now()
>>>
>>> diff = now - earlier
>>> diff.seconds
10
```

convert your strings to datetime objects with [time.strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime)

```
datetime.strptime("2015-08-10 19:33:27.653", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Answer (score 3):

`timedelta.seconds` does not represent the total number of seconds in the timedelta, but the total number of seconds modulus 60.

Call the function `timedelta.total_seconds()` instead of accessing the `timedelta.seconds` property.

Answer (score 1):

For python 3.4, first you'd need to convert the strings representing times into datetime objects, then the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) module has helpful tools work with dates and times.

```
from datetime import datetime

def to_datetime_object(date_string, date_format):
    s = datetime.strptime(date_string, date_format)
    return s

time_1 = '2015-08-10 19:33:27'
time_2 = '2015-08-10 19:31:28'
date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
time_1_datetime_object = to_datetime_object(time_1, date_format)
time_2_datetime_object = to_datetime_object(time_2, date_format)

diff_time = time_1_datetime_object - time_2_datetime_object
```