# Cumulative elapsed minutes from Pandas datetime Series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a column of datetime stamps.  I need a column of total minutes elapsed from the first to the last value.

I have:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [
...     pd.Timestamp('2001-01-01 06:00:00'),
...     pd.Timestamp('2001-01-01 06:01:00'),
...     pd.Timestamp('2001-01-01 06:15:00')
... ]})

>>> df
            timestamp
0 2001-01-01 06:00:00
1 2001-01-01 06:01:00
2 2001-01-01 06:15:00
```

I need to add a column that gives the running total:

```
timestamp       minutes
1-1-2001 6:00   0
1-1-2001 6:01   1
1-1-2001 6:15   15
1-1-2001 7:00   60
1-1-2001 7:35   95
```

Having a hard time manipulating the datetime Series to allow me to total up the timestamp.

I've looked at a lot of posts and can't find anything that does what I'm trying to do.  Would appreciate any ideas!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to subtract datetimes / timestamps in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929538/how-to-subtract-datetimes-timestamps-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can chain a few methods together:

```
>>> df['minutes'] = df['timestamp'].diff().fillna(0).dt.total_seconds()\
...     .cumsum().div(60).astype(int)

>>> df
            timestamp  minutes
0 2001-01-01 06:00:00        0
1 2001-01-01 06:01:00        1
2 2001-01-01 06:15:00       15
```

Creation:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': [
...     pd.Timestamp('2001-01-01 06:00:00'),
...     pd.Timestamp('2001-01-01 06:01:00'),
...     pd.Timestamp('2001-01-01 06:15:00')
... ]})
```

---

#### Walkthrough

The easiest way to break this down is to separate each intermediate method call.

`df['timestamp'].diff()` gives you a Series of Pandas-equivalent of Python's `datetime.timedelta`, the differences in times from each value to the next.

```
>>> df['timestamp'].diff()
0        NaT
1   00:01:00
2   00:14:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

This contains an N/A value (`NaT`/not a time) because there's nothing to subtract from the first value.  You can simply fill it with the zero-value for timedeltas:

```
>>> df['timestamp'].diff().fillna(0)
0   00:00:00
1   00:01:00
2   00:14:00
Name: timestamp, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Now you need to get an actual integer (minutes) from these objects.  In `.dt.total_seconds()`, `.dt` is an "accessor" that is a way of accessing a bunch of methods that let you work with datetime-like data:

```
>>> df['timestamp'].diff().fillna(0).dt.total_seconds()
0      0.0
1     60.0
2    840.0
Name: timestamp, dtype: float64
```

The result is the incremental second-change as a float.  You need this on a cumulative basis, in minutes, and as an integer.  That's what the final 3 operations do:

```
>>> df['timestamp'].diff().fillna(0).dt.total_seconds().cumsum().div(60).astype(int)
0     0
1     1
2    15
Name: timestamp, dtype: int64
```

Note that `astype(int)` will do rounding if you have seconds that aren't fully divisible by 60.