# How to plot multiple time intervals in pandas overlapped?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have 3 sets of measurements from benchmarking an application with different parameters. Each test ran for the same amount of time but at different timestamps. I want to plot the results overlapping eachother.

The results are stored in a csv file with the following format: timestamp,duration.
I read the results in a pandas dataframe, convert timestamp to date time and make an aggregation to calculate the p90rt which I want to display (code below)

```
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"], unit='ms')
df.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True)
gdf = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=freq)).agg({"duration": q90})
```

I do this for my 3 datasets, then I plot them using matplotlib:

```
ax = gdf_n.plot()
ax = gdf_r.plot(ax=ax)
gdf_p.plot(ax=ax)
plt.axhline(y=3500, color='r', linestyle='-')
```

However, since they were done at different times they are plotted quite far apart. I would like them to overlap (they were all span the same amount of time - 4minutes). I'm looking for some way to normalize the date time index so the 3 plots are overlapped.

df.head()

```
       timestamp  duration  respCode
0  1589464106981       397       200
1  1589464107015       363       200
2  1589464107046       371       200
3  1589464107123       365       200
4  1589464107024       467       200
```

[image: My current attempt]

Comment: You could set them all to have the same index or combine them to one dataframe.

Comment: this is what I want but have not found yet; basically , after grouping, convert index from date time to a sort of list 0, 1, 2 etc for every dataset

Comment: Please could you post your data? Or just show df.head()

Comment: edited in the question to show head( third column is irrelevant )

Comment: Are the other 2 df's the same? You could convert the timestamp to ms (or whatever time unit), so the first index = 0 and then add the time interval for each row.

Comment: yeah, they are identical ; but other timestamps

Comment: Probably the easiest thing to do is subtract the time difference so they all start at the same time, see this Q/A; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929538/how-to-subtract-datetimes-timestamps-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution albeit a bit hacky. I need the timestamp index in order to use the aggregator. So after the aggregation I wrote each dataframe to file and read again to drop the index. Afterwards index was reset and I could plot all of them.

```
gdf.to_csv('data.csv')
tdfn = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
tdfn = tdfn["duration"]
```

[image]