# Subtracting datetime.time values from each other in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have two variables in the data frame `waking` in date time format that I would like to subtract.

```
waking['diff2'] = (waking['waketime1'] - waking['waketime2'])
```

However, I get the error: `unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'`

How do I overcome this?

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to subtract datetimes / timestamps in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929538/how-to-subtract-datetimes-timestamps-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python - Calculate the difference between two datetime.time objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43305577/python-calculate-the-difference-between-two-datetime-time-objects)